# Damaged or Incomplete apps on El Capitan

Tags: applications, macos

I have updated to El Capitan as soon as it came. I faced a lot of issues with SIP enabled, but recently a new issue popped up. Every once in a while the apps installed without using App Store are getting damaged or incomplete.

[image: The error message from Sourcetree]

The apps which are having issues are [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com) and [Fabric](http://fabric.io). I had to delete those apps and reinstall them to make them work again.

My question is, is it normal or is it a bug? If it's normal, how can I fix it?

Comment: This is wandering in to "too broad" category - but what is the error Fabric had? What error for Source Tree? Having lots of errors is hard to generalize and generally you need to be precise and careful to solve each one and then in hindsight, you will have answers to "normal" or "bug"

Comment: @bmike When I open the app it says "You can't open the application because it may be damaged or incomplete". It keeps happening after every few days. I have to reinstall the app. It never happened to me when I had Yosemite.

Comment: @bmike is correct. Without specifics we have no way to help you.

Comment: @KhürtWilliams What kind of specifics? I just got an alert message which doesn't let me open the app.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced something similar for `Voila`, `Omnifocus` etc. I had to delete and re-download from Mac App Store. I guess it is pretty normal after El Capitan upgrade.

Comment: It's not normal, but good to know that reinstalling the application  seems to fix the issue.